# Keep on the same page whenever I update the table in ajax

Tags: html, datatable

I have the following table that returns 2 pages with data.

```js
var data = [{Designacao: "Teste",},
            {Designacao: "Teste1",},
            {Designacao: "Teste2",},
            {Designacao: "Teste3",},];
            
var data1 = [{Designacao: "Teste",},
            {Designacao: "Teste1",},
            {Designacao: "Teste3",},];

$('.atrib-prod').on("click", function () {
  $("#atribprod tbody").empty();
  $('#atribprod').dataTable().fnDestroy();
    var linha = ``;
    Object.keys(data).forEach(i => {
      Designacao = data[i].Designacao;
      linha += `<tr>
                <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${Designacao}</td>
                <td class="text-center text-muted"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success said_prod">Atualizar</button></td>
              </tr>`;

    $("#atribprod tbody").html(linha);
 })   
    $('.atribprod').dataTable({
      "pagingType": "full_numbers",
      "iDisplayLength": 2,
      "oLanguage": {
        "sProcessing": "Aguarde enquanto os dados são carregados ...",
        "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registos por página",
        "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registo correspondente ao criterio encontrado",
        "sInfoEmpty": "Exibindo 0 a 0 de 0 registos",
        "sInfo": "Exibindo de _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ registos",
        "sInfoFiltered": "",
        "sSearch": "<i class='metismenu-icon pe-7s-search'></i>",
        "oPaginate": {
          "sFirst": "<i class='fa fa-fast-backward' aria-hidden='true'></i>",
          "sPrevious": "<i class='fa fa-backward' aria-hidden='true'></i></span>",
          "sNext": "<i class='fa fa-forward' aria-hidden='true'></i>",
          "sLast": "<i class='fa fa-fast-forward' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
        }
      }
  });
});

$(document).on('click', '.said_prod', function () {
    $("#atribprod tbody").empty();
    $('#atribprod').dataTable().fnDestroy();
    var linha = ``;
    Object.keys(data1).forEach(i => {
      Designacao = data1[i].Designacao;
      linha += `<tr>
                <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${Designacao}</td>
                <td class="text-center text-muted"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success said_prod">Atualizar</button></td>
              </tr>`;

    $("#atribprod tbody").html(linha);
 })   
    $('.atribprod').dataTable({
      "pagingType": "full_numbers",
      "iDisplayLength": 2,
      "oLanguage": {
        "sProcessing": "Aguarde enquanto os dados são carregados ...",
        "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registos por página",
        "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registo correspondente ao criterio encontrado",
        "sInfoEmpty": "Exibindo 0 a 0 de 0 registos",
        "sInfo": "Exibindo de _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ registos",
        "sInfoFiltered": "",
        "sSearch": "<i class='metismenu-icon pe-7s-search'></i>",
        "oPaginate": {
          "sFirst": "<i class='fa fa-fast-backward' aria-hidden='true'></i>",
          "sPrevious": "<i class='fa fa-backward' aria-hidden='true'></i></span>",
          "sNext": "<i class='fa fa-forward' aria-hidden='true'></i>",
          "sLast": "<i class='fa fa-fast-forward' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
        }
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.4.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.4.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.4.2/js/buttons.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>

<button class="nav-link btn-show atrib-prod mobile-toggle-nav">
  Produtos
</button>
<table class="align-middle mb-0 table table-borderless table-striped table-hover atribprod" id="atribprod">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">Colaborador</th>
      <th class="text-center">Ação</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>                                                        
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem I have is that whenever I am on the second page of the table and click on the update button, the table always returns to the first sheet when refreshed.

I intend that when doing the refresh, it updates the page but remains on the same sheet it was on before updating.

Can you help me solve this problem?